# Ubuntu 18.04.1 really slow on very good laptop

Tags: graphics, performance, gnome-shell

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 in my new laptop, alongside Windows 10, and is extremely slow. My specs as reported by Ubuntu:

[image: Specs]

What I've done so far:

- Used `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
  [image: Current drivers installed]
- Set processor to performance mode using `sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance`

  [image: Configured X Server to Maximum Performance]

At this point is better but still very bad, with Chromium with 3 tabs open and doing a search for "Screenshot" the computer just freezes for 3 seconds at least.

[image: Just another print that I could get from the <code>htop</code> command.]

Is there anything that I forgot to do when installing Ubuntu? I've made the same setup on various computers and it was always pretty straightforward, this never happened to me, the system is just unusable for anything.

Edit: This is so slow that a VirtualBox VM is faster. Therefore I've been using the VM instead of the natively installed Ubuntu

Comment: Are you using a beta (field test) snap version of Chromium? Try a non-snap version of Google Chrome (stable). Report back to @heynnema

Comment: There have been occurrences of relatively low "TDP" (package power limit) i7 chips going into power throttling mode, if enabled. The way to check is to use the turbotstat program (part of the linux tools common package) in non-quite mode. The  big spew of information when it starts will have 1 line or 2 about package power limits and if they have been tripped (I think, I never tripped mine) and if they are enabled or disabled. Run `sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt --interval 15` for about 3 minutes and post the output.

Comment: @heynnema I think it's not browser related since I get the same problem with any programs in Ubuntu

Comment: @DougSmythies  There you go! https://pastebin.com/Gys81AHB I'm kind of a Ubuntu newbie so I don't know many of the things that are there to be honest.

Comment: @Samuel : Seems to be working properly. If this line ever changes `PKG Limit #1: ENabled (15.000000 Watts, 28.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)`, please post the new values.

Comment: Use `prime-select intel` and reboot to disable nVidia and see if your Kabylake GPU runs faster. If so then we can narrow down the problem. FTR my skylake works great as long as everything is configured properly.

Comment: I strongly suggest to use LinuxMint. It handles way much better nvidia drivers.